# Get user input in Android app to change TextView text

Tags: java, android, dialog, prompt

I have a `TextView` with some default text, but when a particular file exists it should prompt the user for new text for the TextView. Is there a simple way to do this?

I know what the if statement should be, but not how to get the user response.

In JavaScript I would have done something like:

```
var newText = prompt("What should the new text be?");
myElement.text = newText;
```

Comment: whats wrong with edittext ??? though you can call setText method on textview

Comment: The TextView is used like a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Dialog`/`DialogFragment` that includes an `EditText` (and potentially some further validation) to get the user's input.

[This Android-Developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) covers exactly this scenario and should answer all your questions.